# Xceed Datagrid Test Automation using UFT and TestComplete

Tags: wpf, automation, xceed, xceed-datagrid

I am currently trying to automate one windows application .it has Xceed datagrid .
I tried with UFT and TestComplete automation tool.
I am not able to get the row element from the Xceed grid table.its is identifying as a wpfobject .So i am not able to  get the value from the table when the table gets updated

Can any one please suggest me which tool supports Xceed Grid  completely .

​

Answer (score 0):

No tools support it as of now. UFT next version may support it.